# Algorithm to find possible combinations in Matlab with one constraint?

Tags: matlab, combinations, linear-programming

A very simple example :

`A=[100 250 300]`

How do I find all possible combinations as long as each combination has a sum of **less than 500 ?**

Comment: Is your array always of size 3?

Comment: To clarify, for the above example you want to return [250 100], [100], [250], [300], [300 100]?

Comment: @learnvst Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple code

```
A=[100 250 300];
p = perms(A);

for nn = 1:numel(A)    
    p(sum(p(:,1:nn), 2) < 500, 1:nn)
end
```

Gives the following output

```
ans =

   300
   300
   250
   250
   100
   100

ans =
   300   100
   250   100
   100   250
   100   300
```

If you want to remove duplicates, like [300 100] and [100 300], simply use the `sort` command to sort the values and then you can remove duplicates using `unique`

Comment: Can you explain how to remove duplicates ? I can't get it to work.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `unique`, specifically the bit about `C = unique(A,'rows') `

Answer (score 1):

This code should work. The result will be stored in the cell array `C`:

```
A = [100 250 300];
B = 500;
C = cell(0);

for i = 1:size(A,2)
    D = nchoosek(A,i);
    for j = 1:size(D,1)
        if (sum(D(j,:)) < B)
            C{end+1} = D(j,:);
        end
    end
end
```

or more compact:

```
A = [100 250 300];
B = 500;
C = cell(0);

for i = 1:size(A,2)
    C = [C; num2cell(nchoosek(A,i),2)];
end
C = C(cellfun(@(x) sum(x), C) < B);
```